# PHP: Have an existing 2D array and want to add another column from a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to generate a 2-dimensional array that expands as I add the results from multiple SQL queries.  I'm struggling with 2 different problems depending on how I approach the issue.

The initial query

```
$query = "SELECT YEAR(`Date`) as Year, count(*) as Total FROM `t_Table` GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`)";
if ($result = $mysqli -> query($query)) {
    while($row = $result -> fetch_array()) {
        <some action to get these results into a 2-D array>
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

**Approach 1:  use Year as the index**

The following works to create the array but uses a numeric index:

```
$arr_result[] = array("Year" => $row["Year"], "Total" => $row["Total"]);
```

This produces:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [Year] => 2015 [Total] => 158322 )
    [1] => Array ( [Year] => 2016 [Total] => 47908 )
)
```

What do I need to do to make Year the index?  I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$arr_result[$row["Year"]] = "TotApts" => $row["TotApts"]);
```

and this:

```
$arr_result[$row[0]]["TotApts"] => $row["TotApts"];
```

What am I missing?

**Approach 2:  keep the index numeric and add additional columns to each row**

So bring in query number 2 which extracts Year and count of Gender from the DB and I've verified that all is good as follows:

```
while($row = $result -> fetch_array()) {
    printf("Year %s - Gender %s<br>", $row["Year"], $row["Gender"]);
}
```

This produces

```
Year 2015 - Gender 91819
Year 2016 - Gender 27930
```

But I'm banging my head as to how to insert these into $arr_result so that I produce the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [Year] => 2015 [Total] => 158322 [Gender] => 91819 )
    [1] => Array ( [Year] => 2016 [Total] => 47908 [Gender] => 27930 )
)
```

For example, I've tried among many many other (equally wrong) permutations:

```
$arr_result[][$row["Year"] = array("Gender" => $row["Gender"]);
```

Given use of the numeric index, do I need to loop through them (from i = 0 to x) from within the fetch_array() while loop and check that Year = the query year and only then update the value?  Seems like that's a bit of unnecessary complexity.  Am sure there is simpler approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in the first approach:

```
$arr_result[$row["Year"]]["TotApts"] = $row["TotApts"];
```

In the second approach you can do this:

`$arr_result[] = array( Year" => $row["Year"], "Total" => $row["TotApts"], "Gender" => $row["Gender"] )`

Comment: Thank you - this works a treat and has also helped me solve number 2